# How to create Managed Metadata column using REST API?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I want to create a list managed metadata column, using the request to the endpoint `_api/web/Lists(guid'####-####-#####')/fields`, but with no luck, got such an error `"One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields."` Can someone provide me with a solution to my problem?

Here is the example:

**POST** `https://sites/site/_api/web/Lists(guid'####-####-#####')/fields`

with the body:

```
{
  "AllowMultipleValues": false,
  "AnchorId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "AutoIndexed": false,
  "CanBeDeleted": true,
  "ClientSideComponentId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "ClientSideComponentProperties": null,
  "CreateValuesInEditForm": false,
  "CustomFormatter": null,
  "DefaultFormula": null,
  "DefaultValue": "",
  "DependentLookupInternalNames": [],
  "Description": "",
  "Direction": "none",
  "EnforceUniqueValues": false,
  "EntityPropertyName": "MM",
  "FieldTypeKind": 0,
  "Filterable": true,
  "FromBaseType": false,
  "Group": "Custom Columns",
  "Hidden": false,
  "Indexed": false,
  "InternalName": "MM",
  "IsAnchorValid": true,
  "IsDependentLookup": false,
  "IsKeyword": false,
  "IsPathRendered": false,
  "IsRelationship": true,
  "IsTermSetValid": true,
  "JSLink": "SP.UI.Taxonomy.js|SP.UI.Rte.js(d)|SP.Taxonomy.js(d)|ScriptForWebTaggingUI.js(d)",
  "LookupField": "Term$Resources:core,Language;",
  "LookupList": "{af06326b-1915-48f2-8259-7201ee078854}",
  "LookupWebId": "ea352058-5ae8-4e64-95b2-4cee1b0f46c9",
  "Open": true,
  "PinnedToFiltersPane": false,
  "PrimaryFieldId": null,
  "ReadOnlyField": false,
  "RelationshipDeleteBehavior": 0,
  "Required": false,
  "SchemaXml": "<Field Type=\"TaxonomyFieldType\" DisplayName=\"MM\" List=\"{af06326b-1915-48f2-8259-7201ee078854}\" WebId=\"ea352058-5ae8-4e64-95b2-4cee1b0f46c9\" ShowField=\"Term1033\" Required=\"FALSE\" EnforceUniqueValues=\"FALSE\" ID=\"{ebcf3604-5913-4349-a071-f41570148eec}\" SourceID=\"{e8776034-8684-4238-9519-94443a65381e}\" StaticName=\"MM\" Name=\"MM\" ColName=\"int1\" RowOrdinal=\"0\" Version=\"1\"><Default /><Customization><ArrayOfProperty><Property><Name>SspId</Name><Value xmlns:q1=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" p4:type=\"q1:string\" xmlns:p4=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">a1796552-9a87-4f1d-95d5-b4a3fc8f143d</Value></Property><Property><Name>GroupId</Name></Property><Property><Name>TermSetId</Name><Value xmlns:q2=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" p4:type=\"q2:string\" xmlns:p4=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">67332539-d286-45b3-bf47-21a294ae4b4f</Value></Property><Property><Name>AnchorId</Name><Value xmlns:q3=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" p4:type=\"q3:string\" xmlns:p4=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Value></Property><Property><Name>UserCreated</Name><Value xmlns:q4=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" p4:type=\"q4:boolean\" xmlns:p4=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">false</Value></Property><Property><Name>Open</Name><Value xmlns:q5=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" p4:type=\"q5:boolean\" xmlns:p4=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">true</Value></Property><Property><Name>TextField</Name><Value xmlns:q6=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" p4:type=\"q6:string\" xmlns:p4=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">{b21a872f-ff59-442f-bcce-134621d3a522}</Value></Property><Property><Name>IsPathRendered</Name><Value xmlns:q7=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" p4:type=\"q7:boolean\" xmlns:p4=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">false</Value></Property><Property><Name>IsKeyword</Name><Value xmlns:q8=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" p4:type=\"q8:boolean\" xmlns:p4=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">false</Value></Property><Property><Name>TargetTemplate</Name></Property><Property><Name>CreateValuesInEditForm</Name><Value xmlns:q9=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" p4:type=\"q9:boolean\" xmlns:p4=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">false</Value></Property><Property><Name>FilterAssemblyStrongName</Name><Value xmlns:q10=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" p4:type=\"q10:string\" xmlns:p4=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Value></Property><Property><Name>FilterClassName</Name><Value xmlns:q11=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" p4:type=\"q11:string\" xmlns:p4=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField</Value></Property><Property><Name>FilterMethodName</Name><Value xmlns:q12=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" p4:type=\"q12:string\" xmlns:p4=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">GetFilteringHtml</Value></Property><Property><Name>FilterJavascriptProperty</Name><Value xmlns:q13=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" p4:type=\"q13:string\" xmlns:p4=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">FilteringJavascript</Value></Property></ArrayOfProperty></Customization></Field>",
  "Scope": "/sites/...",
  "Sealed": false,
  "ShowInFiltersPane": 0,
  "Sortable": true,
  "SspId": "a1796552-9a87-4f1d-95d5-b4a3fc8f143d",
  "StaticName": "MM",
  "TargetTemplate": null,
  "TermSetId": "67332539-d286-45b3-bf47-21a294ae4b4f",
  "TextField": "b21a872f-ff59-442f-bcce-134621d3a522",
  "Title": "MM",
  "TypeAsString": "TaxonomyFieldType",
  "TypeDisplayName": "Managed Metadata",
  "TypeShortDescription": "Managed Metadata",
  "UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary": false,
  "UserCreated": false,
  "ValidationFormula": null,
  "ValidationMessage": null,
  "odata.id": "id-value",
  "odata.type": "SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField"
}
```

error:

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "-2130575340, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields."
        }
    }
}
```